# EWS Max Subscription limit reached

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to connect to an 2013 Exchange Server with Java EWS, using Streaming subscriptions, however, after several days of testing, the server is now responding, on some accounts, with this:

> You have exceeded the available subscriptions for your account. 
>   Remove unnecessary subscriptions and try your request again

I understand that this problem is due to the EWSMaxSubscriptions parameter, but in this case, this value can not be changed. I'm looking to close all existing subscriptions, via EWS or with the Exchange Shell but I haven't found any method.

I lost all the subscriptions Ids, and I don't known if they will automatically expire or if they will be forever allocated in the server. So the question is, can I close the subscriptions in any way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why couldn´t the value not be changed? You can setup a new Trotteling Policy, adjust the values to a higher one and assign that new trotteling policy to your affected task user.

Answer (score 0):

How long a streaming notifications will live depends on what you set the lifetime/timeout value you used when you created the subscription, the max you can set this to is 30 minutes so it they won't live any longer then that. You can't enumerate active Subscriptions this has always been a pain point IMO if you have the subscriptionId's you can test if they are still valid so its generally important to store these Id's.

Comment: For some reason, the subscriptions are not being closed after many hours, so I can't free the resources on the server